# SimpleSAMLphp shows saml2-acs.php not found (error 404) when integrating with Microsoft Azure Directory SSO using SAML2

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have created a link from my web directory such that `https://resolute.organization.in/sso` points to the simplesaml directory `/var/www/simplesamlphp/www`

My simpleSAML configuration page:

[image: SimpleSAML Configuration page]

The complete link `https://resolute.organization.in/sso/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp` shows `404 Not Found` while testing *Authentication Sources --> default-sp*.

[image: Test Authentication Sources]

My **config.php:**

```
$config = ['baseurlpath' => 'https://resolute.organization.in/sso/',
          'secretsalt' => 'my_secret_salt',
          'auth.adminpassword' => 'my_admin_pass',
          ];
```

Rest all are default values in **config.php**

My **authsources.php:**

```
$config = [
    'admin' => [
         'core:AdminPassword',
    ],
    'default-sp' => [
        'saml:SP',
        'entityID' => 'https://resolute.organization.in/',
        'idp' => 'https://sts.windows.net/{some-unique-key}/', //From metadata.xml for the app with entity ID in AD as *https://resolute.organization.in/*
        'discoURL' => null,
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
        'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'eduPersonTargetedID',
    ],
]
```

My metadata array in **saml20-idp-remote.php:**

```
 $metadata['https://sts.windows.net/{some-unique-key}/'] = array (
   'entityid' => 'https://sts.windows.net/{some-unique-key}/',
   'contacts' =>
   array (
   ),
   'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
   'SingleSignOnService' =>
   array (
     0 =>
     array (
       'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
       'Location' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{some-unique-key}/saml2',
     ),
     1 =>
     array (
       'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
       'Location' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{some-unique-key}/saml2',
     ),
   ),
   'SingleLogoutService' =>
   array (
     0 =>
     array (
       'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
       'Location' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{some-unique-key}/saml2',
     ),
   ),
   'ArtifactResolutionService' =>
   array (
   ),
   'NameIDFormats' =>
   array (
   ),
   'keys' =>
   array (
     0 =>
     array (
       'encryption' => false,
       'signing' => true,
       'type' => 'X509Certificate',
       'X509Certificate' => '{really_long_key}',
     ),
   ),
 );
```

My Federation page:

[image: Federation page]

The [show metadata] link shows 404 as well, the link in the URL bar in this case is:

```
https://resolute.organization.in/sso/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp?output=xhtml
```

IdP metadata link shows the metadata array properly.

Please help me out with what am I missing here as I have been breaking my head over this for a few days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how php handles the url parameters and occurs when using php-fpm either with NGINX or Apache mpm_worker/event.
In order to fix this, set
`cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue, it had something to do with Nginx server configuration that could not handle multiple php pages in one link. Switched to Apache and everything works fine.